# Pasting the copied data from one column to another column dynamically through vba

Tags: vba, excel

(E.g.) I have pasted the copied data to k5,k6,k7,k8,k9,k10,11,12,13,18,19 and for the next month if I run the macro then it will be pasted to L5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,18,19 and incrementally it will go on to m,n,o for the future months. Could you please anyone suggest how to do this?

My code:

```
Sub Get_Data()

Dim sh As Worksheet, myRange As Range

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Hide")

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B1").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B2").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B3").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B4").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B5").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B6").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B7").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B8").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B9").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K13").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B10").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Range("B11").Copy
Worksheets("FP Support WPOs").Range("K19").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Hide").Cells.ClearContents


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a bit and determine, dynamically, the last filled column in the sheet using:

```
Dim lc As Long
With Sheets("FP Support WPOs")
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

Using that, you can paste into the next column all of the data you want (will use value=value):

```
Dim lc As Long, i as long, j as variant
j = array("5", "6", "7") 'you can fill rest
With Sheets("FP Support WPOs")
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    for i = 1 to 11
        .cells(j(i-1),lc+1).value = sheets("Hide").cells(i,"B").value
    next i
End With
```

Note the use of the array for the non-contiguous paste range, while using the loop for the contiguous copy range.

You could also loop through the array, lbound to ubound, using i = i+1 to count the contiguous iterations, which should lead to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

from your narrative, values are being copied in adjacent columns from K rightwards

then you could count the values from K5 rightwards and start pasting values from the first empty cells

```
Sub Get_Data()
    With Worksheets("FP Support WPOs")
        .Range("K5:K15").Offset(, WorksheetFunction.Count(.Range("K5", .Cells(5, .Columns.Count)))).Value = Worksheets("Hide").Range("B1:B11").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Narendran, any feedback?